# SSRS Static image in report Page irrespective of no of Pages not in header and footer

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

First, There is no header and footer in Page
i have a requirement to show a image of length exact of a page and width 1in and That image should repeat in every page as it irrespective of data that comes

Ex:
if i run that report on one record the total number of output pages is 5 and another record  total number of pages is 8, it differ so on

The body contains a detail row for one record it gives 100 lines and for another records it gives 400 line, So the number of pages depends on the data present in record. How to get the static page repeated in total number of pages ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the image as the background image of the report body, however it will take the full size of your report. Alternatively you can insert the image in the report.

[image]

Then select the image and press `F4` to see the properties window, look for the `Other` node and set the `RepeatWith` property to the tablix that expands across multiple pages.

[image]